# Tag edit suggestion: Microsoft Lumia 640XL

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, editing

Hie.

I noticed that there is a tag named [nokia-lumia-640xl](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia-640xl), but in actuality, the device is named "**Microsoft Lumia 640XL**". Wouldn't it be more accurate of the tag was renamed to [lumia-640-xl](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-640-xl), getting rid of the Nokia part.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer changing it to [microsoft-lumia-640-xl](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-lumia-640-xl) as both Microsoft's [website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/mobile/phone/lumia640-xl-dual-sim/) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Lumia_640) mentions Lumia 640 XL as Microsoft Lumia 640 XL.

Answer (score 2):

Yup.I am totally agree with your point. In fact I am tired of using **[nokia-lumia-535](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia-535)** tag for my Microsft Lumia 535. We should in fact change all the **Nokia lumia** tags and replace them by **[lumia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia)** tags. If not possible then, we should at least change the tag names for Lumia devices marked Microsoft. As far as I know there are only 12 devices marked Microsoft namely Microsoft Lumia 430, Microsoft Lumia 435, Microsoft Lumia 532, Microsoft Lumia 535, Microsoft Lumia 540, Microsoft Lumia 550, Microsoft Lumia 640, Microsoft Lumia 640XL, Microsoft Lumia 650, Microsoft Lumia 950 and Microsoft Lumia 950XL. So it would not be a very big deal if we rename 12 or some tags.